# mesos master with single quorum

Tags: mesos

during the test with 2 master nodes(2 quorum), the source and frameworks are not visible normally.

so I changed the quorum from 2 to 1 and it works normally.

problems occur in all cases with quorum greater than 2.

This happens the same when one master node instead of two.

Is it a problem that I'm using single cpu?

What is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Number of masters must be odd and quorum set to `N/2+1`.

> The size of the quorum of replicas when using replicated_log based registry. It is imperative to set this value to be a majority of masters i.e., quorum > (number of masters)/2. NOTE: Not required if master is run in standalone mode (non-HA).